# Getting full registry key path from value with powershell

Tags: powershell

So I know, what value I am looking for, but I don't know the full path to that value, since its in

`"HKLM\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist"`, so user/profile ID?

So lets say I take a user called **"computer_user_01"**. That means, that his **"ProfileImagePath"** is `"C:\users\computer_user_01"`.

So lets say the full path to that value is:

```
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-3548956479-1181130828-1993911463-1001\ProfileImagePath\C:\users\computer_user_01".
```

So I need the `S-1-5-21-3548956479-1181130828-1993911463-1001\`.

How can I get it from the ProfileImagePath key, `C:\Users\computer_user_01` value ?

Right now I can query the ProfileImagePath key, but it gives me all users:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "hklm:\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist\*\" -Name "ProfileImagePath"
```

How can I specify it further, lets say this worked:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "hklm:\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist\*\" -Name "ProfileImagePath" -Value "C:\users\computer_user_01"
```

Hope you can understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following :

```
# First I get the SID    
$sid = (gwmi win32_useraccount | ? {$_.name -eq "computer_user_01"}).SID
# Then the value of the property you look for
(Get-ItemPropertyValue "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$sid\"   -Name "ProfileImagePath")
```

Comment: Was just about to answer along these lines. You already know the SID so why guess.

Comment: @emits wrote "So I need the "S-1-5-21-3548956479-1181130828-1993911463-1001\", That's why.

Comment: I suppose I meant. There are other ways to get the SID without hunting.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you used  `Get-ItemProperty -Path "hklm:\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist\*\"`, each Object returned has an attribute `ProfileImagePath` and `PSChildName`, which hold everything you need.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "hklm:\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist\*\" | ? {$_.ProfileImagePath -eq "C:\users\computer_user_01"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName
```

Returns the wanted `S-1-5-21-3548956479-1181130828-1993911463-1001`

**Explanation:**

`? {$_.ProfileImagePath -eq "C:\users\computer_user_01"}` - Find the Object with the `ProfileImagePath` of you Path

`Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName` - Output the name of the Object-Adult

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "hklm:\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist\*\" -Name "ProfileImagePath" | 
 Where-Object { $_.ProfileImagePath -eq 'C:\users\computer_user_01' }).PSChildName
```